# Concatenating tensors in Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, concatenation

I want to concatenate a variable and a tensor in Tensorflow, but Tensorflow wouldn't let those two types concatenate.

Here's how I concatenate the two tensors:

```
self.embedded_chars = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.W, self.input_x) //returns Tensor object
v1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([88,77]),dtype=tf.float32)
self.embedded_chars = tf.concat(1,[self.embedded_chars,v1])
```

But I am getting the following error:

> File "test.py", line 93, in 
>       l2_reg_lambda=FLAGS.l2_reg_lambda)   File "test.py", line 31, in **init**
>       self.embedded_chars = tf.concat(1,[self.embedded_chars,v1])   File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line
>   1047, in concat
>       dtype=dtypes.int32).get_shape(   File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line
>   651, in convert_to_tensor
>       as_ref=False)   File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line
>   716, in internal_convert_to_tensor
>       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)   File
>   "lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py",
>   line 176, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
>       return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)   File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py",
>   line 165, in constant
>       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))   File
>   "lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py",
>   line 367, in make_tensor_proto
>       _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)   File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py",
>   line 302, in _AssertCompatible
>       (dtype.name, repr(mismatch), type(mismatch).**name**)) TypeError: Expected int32, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message'
>   instead.

How can I concatenate the variable and tensor correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using version 1.0: 
If you look at the documentation you see that concat (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat) wants to have values as the first argument, and axis as the second argument.

Your code should be:

```
self.embedded_chars = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.W, self.input_x) //returns Tensor object
v1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([88,77]),dtype=tf.float32)
self.embedded_chars = tf.concat([self.embedded_chars,v1],1)
```

As I did not test it, let me know if it works!

Cheers!

Comment: This is only true as of version 1.0.

Comment: Mmm, fair enough! Was assuming bear used this version. @Bear: what version of Tensorflow are you using?